# Intercept captcha image when webview loaded

Tags: android, webview, captcha

Is it possible to intercept a captcha image without opening the link again?

the captcha re-generate everytime the link opened

i tried with `onLoadResource` but it get different image then the shown one

[Captcha link](https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/capito.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible because of the security concept of the captcha .
for some reason like sniffing attacks !